# how to linearly interpolate the inside, intermediate border area of an image with numpy or scipy or another python compatible library

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, scikit-image

I'm trying to linearly interpolate the artifact within the following infrared image:
[image: image to interpolate]

Is there a compact way to do this with a python compatible library, preferably numpy or scipy?

I've tried a pedestrian approach by interpolating each side individually. The following code should calculate the top border interpolation:

```
top_up = np.copy(image[border - 3:border - 2, border:-border])
top_down = np.copy(image[border:border + 1, border:-border])
dif_top = (top_up - top_down) / 3
image[border - 2:border - 1, border:-border] = top_up - dif_top
image[border - 1:border, border:-border] = top_down + dif_top
```

Remark: 'border' is the distance from the top / bottom / left / right to the END (inside) of the artifact. For instance row[border] is the first row which is correct after the artifact. For this image here, the artifact is two pixels wide.

For some reason the code above only works for a few pixels but not for the entire row. I thought the error might be because slicing only creates a view. I therefore added np.copy but that didn't help.
Here's an image how the 'interpolated' area of the top border looks like:

[image: partially interpolated top border]

As an example, assuming the 0s stand for the black border artifact, the input

```
11111
10001
10301
10001
11111
```

should give

```
11111
12221
12321
12221
11111
```

Comment: Is the artifact always in exactly the same location? Is it always exactly 2 pixels wide?

Comment: The image is the output of a neural network which tries to predict the area around the input image. The image fed is the area within the artifact. The area around it (including the artifact) is predicted. The artifact has different widths, depending on the architecture of the neural network I'm using. It goes up to 5 pixels max. But the start of the artifact (viewed from the inside of the image) is always at the same location 'border'.
I was looking into numpy mgrid and scipy griddata and interolate but I couldn't come up with a solution.

Comment: Funky. `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` should do the job ([docs]https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html). Basically, you want to create a boolean mask for your image with True corresponding to the artifact locations, create an interpolating function using `interp2d` passing in the coordinates and values of all unmasked pixels, and then interpolate at the locations with the masked pixels. Do you know why your gradients at the input image border don't seem to work properly? If I were you, I would try to fix that instead, tbh.